# Why "clickAt" does not work on Vaadin tables?

Tags: vaadin, selenium-ide

I want to test my Vaadin (v7.6.6) tables. But when I use Selenium IDE (2.9.1) in Firefox (47.0), a clickAt event on a table entry does not working (when you click on an entry, the color should change).

My command reads as follows:

```
ClickAt | //*[@id=…']/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

So my target is the entry (1,1) of the table’s body. In FireBug the entry I want to click at reads as follows:

```html
<td class="v-table-cell-content" style="width: 140px;">
<div class="v-table-cell-wrapper" style="text-align: left; width: 140px; background-color: transparent;">2005</div>
</td>
```

When I click on the Button “Find”, it shows me the correct table entry. Additionally a manual click event works fine.

Can anyone help me with my issue?

Comment: Did you double-check your xPath with FirePath?

Comment: Have you already tried the `click` command?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your resonance. I checked the xPath with FirePath. It is correct, because I find the table entry when I click on the Button "Find". I have tested the commands "clickAt", "click" and "MouseUp". Neither of them works. Strangely enough I am able to click on the header entries of the vaadin table with the Selenium IDE commands, but not on the body entries.

Answer (score 0):

Something I found useful when the click event doesn't work I use the fire event command with click in the value and using the target as css=div.v-table-cell-wrapper